# Как получить контроль над появляющимся окном?

Tags: c#, winforms, form, процесс, cefsharp

На c# пишу бота, который самостоятельно заходит на сайты для серфинга, использую библиотеку CefSharp.
Некоторые из сайтов периодически должны открывать как бы "новую вкладку", но в нашем случае запускается новый процесс "CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe" и некая форма, с которой нужно взаимодействовать. При чем, если просто закрыть процесс браузера, то останется вот такое пустое окно.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Закрывается оно только с основной программой, но в процессах ни как не фигурирует, соответственно это дочерняя форма.

Как получить контроль над этим окном или его содержимым?

Желательно control этого окна поместить в Tab-страницу основной программы.

Может быть есть метод, который срабатывает при создании дочерних форм/окон?

Comment: Дочерние окно всегда одно?

Comment: @VladimirT нет, их n-количество.

Comment: можно код, того как вы запускаете это окно?

Comment: @VladimirT инициация запуска окна происходит из web-страницы, на которой я нахожусь через CefSharp. У меня в программе ни как не прописан его запуск.

Comment: Какой нить `Application.OpenForms` ничего полезного не возвращает?

Comment: Пройдитесь по всей коллекции форм и проверьте заголовок каждой из них. Код, что вы показали, мне ни о чем не говорит

Comment: @tym32167 получил коллекцию, спросил, сколько в ней форм, в результате 1, и это главная форма.

Comment: значит этот метод не подойдет. Тогда я бы смотрел на уровень ниже, наверняка есть Winapi метод, который возвращает список окон в процессе

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо, интересно конечно, но если я спрашиваю у дескриптора произвольного окна, кто у него родитель(GetParent), то он выдает, что рабочий стол, а не моя программа.

Comment: спрашивайте у дескриптора нужного вам окна, а не произвольного - ваша программа не может быть парентом просто любого произвольного открытого окна

Comment: @tym32167 нужные мне окна произвольно созданы, естественно я понимаю, что прога не может быть родителем калькулятора на пример... я тут вычитал такое понятие как owner form, но не могу найти функции, которая возвращала бы этого owner...

Comment: Просто для справки - я вообще не в контексте вашей проблемы, если бы знал ответ - написал бы ответом. А так я также, как и вы,просто гадаю :) По поводу овнера - у формы есть поле Owner - может вы про него говорите?

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо, я нашел методы, которыми попросту забираю все лишние формы и запихиваю в контролы на панелях моей программы, теперь другая проблема как правильно отследить открытие этих форм, просто проверять с периодичностью не правильно будет. Если бы в winApi было определение евента.